# How to Remove '%' symbol in jinja and i want to find discount using python?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I'm tired of calculating discounts and want to remove `'%'` from my data on jinja side.

I have data in a jinja template from python where `{{ oss['p_cost'] }}` is 5130 and `{{ oss['offer'] }}` is 5%

I would like to find the discount from this value. I have tried but I can't get the needed output.

Here is what I have already tried:

```
   <p>{{ oss['p_cost']/100*oss['offer'] }}</p>
```

and I want to remove '%' inside `{{oss['offer']}}` this data is like

```
{{ oss['offer'] }} = 5%
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data that you are passing to jinja? (i.e. if there is a `%` sign in `oss['offer']`, then the multiplication between `int` and `string` will not work as expected).

Comment: yes with this oss['offer'] the '%' symbol will be there for that struggle i want to remove '%' symbol from oss['offer']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, you can use the following snippets and tweak them to you needs:

```
{{ oss['offer'] * 100 }}%
```

Will print a percent value like `5%`. If you want to calculate the offer "value", then do something in the lines of:

```
{{ oss['offer']*100 }}% of {{ oss['p_cost']}} is ${{ (oss['p_cost'] * oss['offer'])/100 }}
```

Given your values above (5130 and 0.05), this will print `5% of 5130 is $256.5`.